# UITableView - Sectioned Tableview drilling down into Children subviews then into a Detail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, plist

Is anyone able to post a pList and UITableView code on how to do this?

Basically I want a Sectioned Tableview loaded from a pList file, that can drill down into children sub views and eventually lead into a Detail View. ie..

***::::::::: Food ::::::::: ***
 **- Entree**
 - - Bruschetta
 - - - > *Detail view*
 - - Garlic Bread
 - - - > *Detail View*
 **- Mains**
 - - Steak Rump
 - - - > *Detail view*
 - - Chicken Breast
 - - - > *Detail View*

***::::::::: Drinks ::::::::: ***
 **- Beer**
 - - Millers
 - - - > *Detail view*
 - - Heiniken
 - - - > *Detail view*
 **- Wine**
 - - Cabernet Merlot
 - - - > *Detail view*
 - - Cabernet Sav
 - - - > *Detail view*

Comment: This question would have been regarded as too broad back in 2011, and somehow it escaped closure. The rules are significantly tighter now, and it is just by luck that this is still open. It is far too broad based on the posting guidelines in force today.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface SectionsViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
NSDictionary *names;
NSArray *keys;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *names;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *keys;    
@end
```

Now, switch over to SectionsViewController.m, and add the following code to the beginning of that file:

```
#import "SectionsViewController.h"
@implementation SectionsViewController
@synthesize names;
@synthesize keys; 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOURpLISTfILE" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.names = dict; [dict release];
NSArray *array = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
self.keys = array;
}
```

And add the following code at the end of the file, just above the @end declaration:

```
#pragma mark 
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods - 
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
return [keys count];
}
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:     (NSInteger)section
 { NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
 return [nameSection count];
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 NSUInteger section = [indexPath section]; NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SectionsTableIdentifier;
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row]; return cell;

(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
 NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; return key;
}
@end
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'structure'? And yeah accept it if it helped :)

Comment: i updated the original post to show i need the tableview to be set and drilled down into. will that work with your code? cheers :)